# heron activate Error: cluster/role/environ does not match. Topology 'WordCountTopology' is running at local/root/default, not local/yitian/default

Tags: heron

As following error happened, when I running Twitter Heron on local machine using the command:

```
heron activate local WordCountTopology.
```

The error information:

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# heron activate local WordCountTopology
[2017-12-02 05:23:32 +0000] [INFO]: Using cluster definition in /usr/local/heron/conf/local
[2017-12-02 05:23:32 +0000] [ERROR]: cluster/role/environ does not match. Topology 'WordCountTopology' is running at local/root/default, not local/yitian/default
[2017-12-02 05:23:32 +0000] [ERROR]: Failed to activate topology: WordCountTopology
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be great if we can see the verbose logs - can you please do the following?

```
heron activate local --verbose WordCountTopology
```

It will print several logs and this will help identify if there is an issue.

Comment: Based on hidden part of the logs, it looks you launched the topology as 'root' and you are trying to activate the topology by the user 'yitian' - that could be an issue. Try activating the topology as 'root' - which is the original user that launched the topology.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I have solved the problem. There are some exception when Heron 0.17.1 running on the CentOS 6.4 version. It is normal when heron running on Centos 7. Although this problem can be solved by using following command: $ heron activate local/root/default WordCountTopology, it is suggestion that using CentOS 7 version deploy heron.